# issue with user interface in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Hi i am currently doing this leave project and the user interface have problems when changing computer. I have added a code to change the DPI which was supposed to solve the problem based on the computer.The code that was used is:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
            SetProcessDPIAware();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }
}
}
```

This is the display for the computer with problem:
[image: Computer with problem]

This is the display for the computer that does not have the problem:
[image: Computer that does not have the problem]

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Ok, first up you have *code to change the DPI* - please do **not** change users accessibility settings to make your program work. Change your program to work with any display/resolution/DPI configuration. Second try using a Table layout &/or Anchors and Docking control properties. Third, where is your code to show us how you have layed it out?

Comment: Which code do you mean?There is no code for laying it out it is windows form it is dragged from the toolbox and drop in the form @JeremyThompson

Comment: Put the mouse cursor on the `InitializeComponent` call in the Constructor of Login.cs. Press F12 to goto definition, this is how you get to see the login.designer.cs file. Show us that code and tell us which resolutions we need to reproduce the problem. Since you are new here please read this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/